# path helper rails return "MODEL.ID" instead of "MODEL/ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, path, helper

I have a AR model named "topic".

I try to use helper path like :

```
topic_path(42) # return => "domaine.exemple/topic.42" instead of "domaine.exemple/topic/42"
```

my routes has generated by "ressource"

```
resource :topic, shallow: true
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `resources` (plural), not `resource` (singular) since you have multiple resources:

```
resources :topics, shallow: true
```

Comment: Frel... It's just that. thx ! But model name have to stay at singular: "ressources :topic ...."